# Upgrading from asp.net 3.5 to asp.net 4.0 causes javascript-error on some postbacks

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, asp.net-4.0, iis-7.5

I have recently begun upgrading an existing and working .net website from ASP.NET v3.5 to v4.0 and the strangest thing occur.

When submitting web forms I get a javascript error like:

> Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
>   Details: Error parsing near '�'.
>   Line: 5
>   Char: 84093
>   Code: 0
>   URI: http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js

Notice the strange characters near "Details: Error parsing near"? Using Firebug, I was able to get the entire response (in unicode) which looks like this:

> ������ì½`I%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡`$Ø@ìÁÍæìiG#)«*ÊeVe]f@Ìí¼÷Þ{ï½÷Þ{ï½÷º;N'÷ßÿ?\fdlöÎJÚÉ!ªÈ?~|?"væÇægöfÿþÏ¬²üU>+ê|ÚþÌÏüî{ç«:oºªÍï_Mûû7ùt]çã¬Y½ûÝï/ªYþ»ß5Ùe>ûÿ'��ÿÿ¿Þv5F���

This makes no sense at all, and I honestly don't know how to fix it.
Now I have tried to set various things like controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" in web.config, removing/adding

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
```

to the header, reinstalling asp.net using aspnet_regiis -i from the 4.0 framework directory, restarted IIS, turned off EnableCdn on the scriptmanager tag to use local script files instead of the hostet cdn, tried various browsers (IE8, FF3.6.13, Opera, Safari). No luck. Next option will probably be a big sledge hammer.

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate **64 bit**, have tried with IIS 7.5 and builtin ASP.NET webserver of VS2010 - same problem in both IIS.

Can anybody suggest a solution (other than the sledge hammer)?

Comment: This shouldn't fix it, but would it help with those characters? <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />

Comment: Hi PandaWood - thanks for replying. Unfortunately that did not solve the problem. Strange characters remain, even after adding the globalization tag to web.config.

Comment: Any other suggestions, anyone? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have something to do with some custom http modules you have that change the response content on the fly... may be something to merge css/js files...

It's hard to tell without having access to your code.

You might try to disable some custom modules if you have any

Comment: Thanks for reply and sorry my late answer. I have upgraded our custom built modules to 4.0 - no luck. I have also tried to turn off our ViewState compression routine, which we have borrowed from here:
https://hspinfo.wordpress.com/category/ajax/
- No luck.
All debugging stops at Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx") - if boolEndResponse param is true, the error will be thrown immediately. If changed to something like Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx",false"), the systems loads the rest of page parts, but when all that is done, error will be thrown again. It is always the Ajax script.

Comment: I finally figured it out - we had a gzip/deflate compression routine in Global.asax that did not work properly with .net 4.0. Eventhough it is not the best fix, specific pages has been removed from being compressed.